# How to convert nametuple to dict in python

Tags: python

I want convert nametuple to dict with python:
I have:

```
CommentInfo(stt=1, gid=12, uid=222)
```

Now I want:

```
{"stt":1,"gid":12,"uid":222}
```

Please help me! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `_asdict()` function to convert the named tuples into a dictionary.

**Example:**

```
>>> CommentInfo = namedtuple('CommentInfo', ["stt", "gid", "uid"])
>>> x = CommentInfo(stt=1,gid=12,uid=222)
>>> x._asdict()
OrderedDict([('stt', 1), ('gid', 12), ('uid', 222)])
```

Answer (score 4):

namedtuples has a `._asdict()` method to convert it to an OrderedDict, so if you have an instance in a variable `comment` you can use `comment._asdict()`